# Regular Expression to remove leading and trailing Angle Brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Using C#, I need to check strings (email addresses) to see if they have leading and trailing angle brackets, and if so, remove them, leaving the email address string intact.

e.g.

```
<john@johnsmith.com> becomes john@johnsmith.com
```

I should probably also cater for the scenario where perhaps there could be white space in front of the leading angle bracket, or behind the trailing angle bracket.

What would be a decent regex to handle this replacement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need to use Regex for this?

You can simply do this:

```
string email = "<john@johnsmith.org>";
email = email.TrimStart('<').TrimEnd('>');
```

Of course if you really need to be sure there's no spaces, or that there might be multiple spaces:

```
string email = "<john@johnsmith.org>";
email = email.Trim().TrimStart('<').TrimEnd('>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use Russ Clarke solution (it is the best in my opinion).

But if you really need a regex....

```
var email = "<john@johnsmith.com>";
email = Regex.Replace(email, "^<|>$", "");
```

Clarification:

```
^< - match start < sign
| - or
>$ - match end > sign
```

Extended version for allowing whitespaces (`\s*` catches whitespaces):

```
email = Regex.Replace(email, @"^\s*<\s*|\s*>\s*$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Although `TrimStart`/`TrimEnd`/`Trim` give you a nice option to complete the task without regex, if you would like to allow spaces around `<` on both sides you would have to perform four calls to do it.

Regex lets you do it in a single call. Here is one possible expression:

```
@"^\s*<?\s*([^\s>]+)\s*>?\s*$"
```

It has `^\s*<?\s*` to match an optional `<` surrounded by optional spaces in the beginning, and `\s*>?\s*$` for a similar match at the end.

The middle portion is a *capturing group* `([^\s>]+)` to match the e-mail address itself, without performing any validation on it.

All you need now is to "paste" the captured middle into the replacement, like this:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"^\s*<?\s*([^\s>]+)\s*>?\s*$", "$1")
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/CU63Ph)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex globally:

```
\<(.*?)\>
```

Explanation:

- `\<` : < is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it
  literally.
- `(.*?)` : match everything in a non-greedy way and capture it.
- `\>` : > is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it
  literally.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this much, you can just do a `String.Replace()` like this

```
var email = " <someone@example.com>";
email = email.Trim().Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "");
```